# How to send a xml that contains list to wcf service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am implementing a wcf restful service and I want to send a xml that contains list of a class to wcf service. Other arguments pass successfully to service but list comes empty.
My xml;

```
    <phoneBookWebServiceSearchResponse xmlns="http://callturksvc.alfion.com.tr">
    <uniqueId>40</uniqueId>
    <webServiceResponseType>SUCCESS</webServiceResponseType>
    <clientQueryNo>0</clientQueryNo>
    <responseMessage>SUCCESS</responseMessage>
    <phoneBookList>
    <phoneBook>
        <cityCode>34</cityCode>
        <cityName>İstanbul</cityName>
        <districtName>Beşiktaş</districtName>
        <firstName>Şuayp</firstName>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2013-01-28T15:30:36.925+02:00</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <lastName>Çiçek</lastName>
        <phoneBookTypeEnumValue>TURKCELL</phoneBookTypeEnumValue>
        <phoneNumberText>5356875946</phoneNumberText>
    </phoneBook>
    </phoneBookList>
    </phoneBookWebServiceSearchResponse>
```

And class that will handle this xml;

```
[DataContract(Name = "phoneBookWebServiceSearchResponse", Namespace ="http://callturksvc.alfion.com.tr")]
public class phoneBookWebServiceSearchResponse
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1, Name = "uniqueId")]
    public string uniqueId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2, Name = "webServiceResponseType")]
    public string webServiceResponseType { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3, Name = "clientQueryNo")]
    public string clientQueryNo { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4, Name = "responseMessage")]
    public string responseMessage { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 5, Name = "phoneBookList")]
    public phoneBookList phoneBookList { get; set; }

    public phoneBookWebServiceSearchResponse()
    {
        uniqueId = string.Empty;
        webServiceResponseType = string.Empty;
        clientQueryNo = string.Empty;
        responseMessage = string.Empty;
        phoneBookList = new phoneBookList();
    }
}


public class phoneBookList
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1, Name = "phoneBook")]
    public List<phoneBook> phoneBook { get; set; }
    public phoneBookList()
    {
        phoneBook = new List<phoneBook>();
    }
}

public class phoneBook
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1, Name = "firstName")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2, Name = "lastName")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3, Name = "cityCode")]
    public string cityCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4, Name = "cityName")]
    public string cityName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 5, Name = "districtName")]
    public string districtName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 6, Name = "lastModifiedDateTime")]
    public string lastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 7, Name = "phoneBookTypeEnumValue")]
    public string phoneBookTypeEnumValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 8, Name = "phoneNumberText")]
    public string phoneNumberText { get; set; }
    public phoneBook()
    {
        firstName = string.Empty;
        lastName = string.Empty;
        cityCode = string.Empty;
        cityName = string.Empty;
        districtName = string.Empty;
        lastModifiedDateTime = string.Empty;
        phoneBookTypeEnumValue = string.Empty;
        phoneNumberText = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Response class is;

```
    [DataContract(Name="CallTurkResponse", Namespace ="http://callturksvc.alfion.com.tr")]
    public class CallTurkResponse
    {
      [DataMember(Name="responseMessage", Order=1)]
      public string responseMessage { get; set; }
     }
```

My service class is;

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "auth")]
    CallTurkResponse Auth(phoneBookWebServiceSearchResponse res);
```

And finally my service is;

```
    public CallTurkResponse Auth(phoneBookWebServiceSearchResponse res)
    {
        return new CallTurkResponse
        {
            responseMessage = "SUCCESS"
        };
    }
```

the problem is that when I sent xml request above, I get uniqueId, webServiceResponseType,
clientQueryNo and responseMessage successfully in debugger.
But phoneBookList comes to service empty.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IEnumerable` instead of List `List<phoneBook>`.

---

Edit:

consider using `IEnumerable` like an option. But also you need few updates to your code. At first, you should mark all classes with `DataContract` Attribute providing the same namespace you have marked `phoneBookWebServiceSearchResponse` class. Other way causes naming conflict in xml. Also it looks you don't need class `phoneBookList` at all.

```
[DataContract(Name = "phoneBookWebServiceSearchResponse", Namespace = "http://callturksvc.alfion.com.tr")]
    public class phoneBookWebServiceSearchResponse
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1, Name = "uniqueId")]
        public string uniqueId { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2, Name = "webServiceResponseType")]
        public string webServiceResponseType { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 3, Name = "clientQueryNo")]
        public string clientQueryNo { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 4, Name = "responseMessage")]
        public string responseMessage { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 5, Name = "phoneBookList")]
        public List<phoneBook> phoneBookList { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 [DataContract(Name = "phoneBook", Namespace = "http://callturksvc.alfion.com.tr")]
    public class phoneBook
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1, Name = "firstName")]
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2, Name = "lastName")]
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 3, Name = "cityCode")]
        public string cityCode { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 4, Name = "cityName")]
        public string cityName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 5, Name = "districtName")]
        public string districtName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 6, Name = "lastModifiedDateTime")]
        public string lastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 7, Name = "phoneBookTypeEnumValue")]
        public string phoneBookTypeEnumValue { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 8, Name = "phoneNumberText")]
        public string phoneNumberText { get; set; }
    }
```